# JSON nested from MySQL (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, json

Database table articles holds parent articles and articles variants.
Variant articles have empty NAME fields, their PARENTID is related to the parents id.
Not every article has variants.

```
parent articles:    ID, NAME   
variant articles:   ID, PARENTID, VARIANT
```

How can ι get a JSON like this?
Only articles with child articles

```
{
  "ID": "dfe17b",
  "NAME": "this is a very good movie",
  "variants": [
    {
      "ID": "6bcb7",
      "VARIANT": "DVD",
    },
    {
      "ID": "75a9b",
      "VARIANT": "Blu-ray",
    },
    {
      "ID": "fe3b3",
      "VARIANT": "VHS",
    }
  ]
},
{
  "ID": "dfe156",
  "NAME": "this is a pretty nice movie",
  "variants": [
    {
      "ID": "5j4h7",
      "VARIANT": "online",
    },
    {
      "ID": "95c9s",
      "VARIANT": "Blu-ray",
    }
  ]
}
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT o.ID, o.PARENTID, IFNULL(oa.TITLE, o.TITLE) AS TITLE,     o.VARNAME,       o.VARSELECT
FROM articles o
  LEFT JOIN articles oa
    ON oa.ID = o.PARENTID
WHERE o.VARNAME IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY TITLE ASC
```

gives

```
{
  "ID": "dfe17b",
  "NAME": "this is a very good movie",
  "VARIANT": "",
  ...
},
{
 "ID": "6bcb7",
  "NAME": "this is a very good movie",
  "VARIANT": "DVD",
   ...
},
{
"ID": "75a9b",
"NAME": "this is a very good movie",
"VARIANT": "Blu-ray",
...
},
{
"ID": "fe3b3",
"NAME": "this is a very good movie",   
"VARIANT": "VHS",
...
},
{
  "ID": "dfe156",
  "NAME": "this is a pretty nice movie",
  "VARIANT": "",
  ...
  },
  {
  "ID": "5j4h7",
  "NAME": "this is a pretty nice movie",
  "VARIANT": "online",
  ...
  },
  {
  "ID": "95c9s",
  "NAME": "this is a pretty nice movie",
  "VARIANT": "Blu-ray",
   ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$parents = array();
$sql = "SELECT ID, NAME FROM articles
WHERE NAME!='' AND PARENTID=''
ORDER BY NAME"; 
$res = $db->db_query($sql);
while ($row=$db->db_fetch_assoc($res)){
$row['variants'] = array();
$parents[$row['ID']] = $row;
}

# variants
$sql = "SELECT ID,PARENTID,VARIANT FROM articles
WHERE PARENTID!=''
ORDER BY NAME"; 
$res = $db->db_query($sql);
while ($row=$db->db_fetch_assoc($res)){
$parents[$row['PARENTID']]['variant'][] = $row;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array_values($parents));
```